# Showing only Boolean 1 as published in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I using boolean for publish and draft, publish = 1 and draft = 0

How do i show data in my view only for data that have value 1 or publish in laravel ?

Here's my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        
        $posts = Post::where('is_active', '1');
        

        return view('pages/home', compact('posts'));
    }
```

Here's my database for Posts:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('post_title', 60);
            $table->string('post_slug')->unique();
            $table->integer('post_seq');
            $table->string('post_thumbnail');
            $table->string('post_excerpt', 500);
            $table->text('post_description');
            $table->string('post_meta_title');
            $table->string('post_meta_description');
            $table->string('post_meta_keyword');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->blameable();
        });
```

And here's my Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = ['post_title', 'post_slug', 'post_thumbnail', 'post_seq', 'post_excerpt', 'post_description', 'post_meta_title', 'post_meta_description', 'post_meta_keyword', 'is_active', 'created_by'];

}
```

Here's my database in mysql

[image]

Anyone can solve it?

Comment: Try `$posts = Post::where( 'is_active', true )->get();` ..

Comment: I did, not changing anything..

Answer (score 1):

You only forgot to execute the query:

```
$posts = Post::where('is_active', '1')->get();
```

Comment: Are you sure, `is_active` corresponds to "published" and "draft"?

Comment: I only use published and draft only as alias, real value is 0 & 1 as boolean.. Because i set when i create data, when they select published it will store as 1 in database (boolean) it also same with when select draft it will store as 0 in database

Comment: I meant whether `is_active` is the right column or not.

Answer (score 0):

try instead string '1' to 1

```
public function index()
    {
        
        $posts = Post::where('is_active', 1)->get();
        

        return view('pages/home', compact('posts'));
    }
```

Comment: i already did, it not changing any of it.. data with `is_active` 0 still show..

Comment: yes i saw.can you post data of posts table .so we can get how data storing in is_acitve

Comment: Yes, i already post screenshot of my database

Comment: i saw .every think looks good.not sure why your query fails.are you sure that still you get all records even though after adding get() to  $posts = Post::where('is_active', 1)->get();

Comment: Yes, i dont know why boolean with value 0 is still showed up hmm..

Comment: can you add one more row with is_active 1 to database table .lets see what you get

Comment: I Solved it, i have to put the query as array in return view.. `return view('posts.index', ['posts' => $posts = Post::where('is_active', '1')->get(),  'myField' => $myField, 'keywords' => $keywords,  'descriptions' => $descriptions]);`

Comment: i really not sure whats the difference of that.but anyway you solved you issue.good lucj

Comment: @SutanFirqy.its okay.np

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it, i have to put the query in return view as an array

`return view('posts.index', ['posts' => $posts = Post::where('is_active', '1')->get(), 'myField' => $myField, 'keywords' => $keywords, 'descriptions' => $descriptions]);`

Thankyou for all your helped..

Comment: You can remove the `$posts =` part